# Number of times number appears in a 2D array

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, counter

```
class Board
{
    int[,] ActiveXY = new int[9, 3];
    private int NumOfActiveCells()
    {     
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (ActiveXY[i, 2] == 1) counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
...
```

In this code, ActiveXY is a 2D array of 9 cells, each having 3 properties: [0] is the X, [1] is the Y, and [2] is if its active or not, being 0 for inactive and 1 for active.

I'm trying to check how many cells are active with NumOfActiveCells(), and though it works, I still wish to see if there is a shorter or even a one-liner way of doing this.
Perhaps something using LINQ?

EDIT: Changed "Better" => "Shorter". I explained myself incorrectly. I do agree that the code I have is just fine, but I just wanted to see if there is a shorter way, thank you for the replies!

Comment: "Better" is a debatable concept. You seem to be under the impression that one-liners are better then multi-liners but there are people who disagree. For me there are usually 2 things important and I try to find a balance between them: readability and speed. And by those standards your code is perfectly fine. It's easy to read and you only access the part of the array (the active flag) that you need, so it works for speed as well. Imo stop thinking everything needs to be fancy-pancy one-liners and be happy with readable and fast code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I 100% agree with you. I fixed my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `int[,]` only implements `IEnumerable` (the non-generic version), you can `Cast<int>` to make it an `IEnumerable<int>`. Then you can use all the usual LINQ operations.

All the elements that you want have an index of `[x, 2]` (third column) in the original 2D array. Since an `IEnumerable<int>` represents a 1D sequence, the 2D array will be flattened and the index `[x, 2]` will be mapped to `3x + 2`. So to check whether an element `e` in the 1D sequence is in the third column in the original 2D array, we just need to see if its index in the 1D sequence can be expressed as `3x + 2`.

```
int total1s = ActiveXY.Cast<int>().Where((e, index) => e == 1 && (index + 1) % 3 == 0).Count();
```

Edit: I just thought of a more readable solution:

```
int total1s = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => ActiveXY[i, 2]).Count(x => x == 1);
```

This works just like your for loop, with an "loop counter" of `i` going from 0 to 8, and counting the elements that match `x == 1`.

Comment: Good solution, but current OP code is more clear and readable, IMO:)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't know what's wrong with me for thinking of such an obscure solution first... I have added a more "orthodox" (?) one...

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for the quick answer, I underestimated this community.
thank you!